# TFS 2015 Release Cannot Get “Run Functional Tests” Task to Work on Multiple Machines

Tags: automated-tests, tfs-2015, ms-release-management

On-prem TFS 2015 Update 3.

I have multiple machines (different Operating Systems) that I want to run my tests on. I'm having issues getting this simple flow to work successfully. Here's what I've tried:

1. Deploy Test Agent task on multiple machines are successful.
2. If I put multiple machines in one "Run Functional Tests" task, it will execute the test one ONE of those machines in step 1 only (and will complete successful if this is the first task). Logs here: [One Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/files/1077767/ReleaseLogs_57.zip)
3. If I set up 2 separate tasks, one for each machine, the 1st task will execute successfully, but as seen in bullet 2, the test is run on ANY ONE of the machines in step 1 (NOT the specific one specified for the task). In the example attached, the 1st task is set up to run on Win7, but the test was actually executed on the Win8 machine.
   Then the 2nd task (which is set up to run against the Win10 machine) will not complete, no matter what machine or test I put in it. Logs for this scenario attached: [Two Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/files/1078061/ReleaseLogs_60.zip)

It seems that the PS script(s) for this task is broken in our environment.

Thanks!

Comment: What about set the test in Release definition? Add multiple environments and add the “Run Functional Tests” Task for each environment separately, each environment for a platform, is that works? Besides, this article for your reference http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/06/04/running-unit-tests-on-different-machine-during-tfs-2015-build/

Comment: Yes if I create 2 separate environments (with just one machine for each task), then they work fine. I suppose this is my workaround until there's a resolution to the other approach, which I think "should" work. Otherwise, every release will have a lot of environments for each combination of OS/Browser.

Comment: Besides, the fact that the task will execute the tests on any of the machines rather than what's specified in its "Machines" setting just seems wrong. What's the purpose of specifying "Machines" if that doesn't matter?

Comment: Try to configure a agent, then run test, then configure another agent and run test. (do not configure them in a task)

Comment: That works!!! I thought I had tried that approach, but that must have slipped among several setups that I tried. I'll take that as a solution for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that you can configure test agent separately: configure a agent, then run test, then configure another agent and run test.